# Django REST nested object serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the current api as set below, and my intention is to make it to show desired output. I'd like to add age and nationality as shown below(see Desired output) to the type as nested, but it seems to only show in straight format not nested. What's best way to make it nested?

```
  "type" : [
    { "age" : "27",  "nationality" : "usa" }
```

Current API

```
[
    {
     "name"    : "Jay",
     "school" : "college",
     "type" : "usa"
     "age": "27"
     "nationality": "usa"

        },
    ]
```

Desired API

```
[
    {
    "name"    : "Jay",
    "school" : "college",
    "type" : [
     { "age" : "27",  "nationality" : "usa" },
     { "age" : "24",  "nationality" : "canada" },
     { "age" : "26",  "nationality" : "thailand" },
  ]
}​
]
```

Serializers.py

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = ("name", "school", "type", "age", "nationality")

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get("name", instance.name)
        instance.school = validated_data.get("school", instance.session)
        instance.type = validated_data.get("type", instance.session)
        instance.age = validated_data.get("age", instance.session)
        instance.nationality = validated_data.get("nationality", instance.session)


    instance.save()
    return instance
```

models.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.name, self.school)
```

views.py

```
class ListSchoolView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Provides a get method handler.
    """
    queryset = School.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
```

Comment: I answered this yesterday but you deleted the question. You should have continued the discussion in that question.

Comment: Type has to have a serializer of its own if you want to achieve your desired format. `TypeSerialzier` will have `age` and `nationality` fields as I explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070860/nested-object-for-rest-framework-django
Your `SchoolSerializer` is `SupervisorSerializer` and the `TypeSerializer` would be like the `ManagerSerializer`.

Comment: If you want to take input as it is currently but just want a different format when the record is retrieved then customized the retrieve view.

Comment: I'm looking to take input in desired api format. I added in more to the API format. Your code did not seem to work. Can you repost on here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the way your model is serialized, override the `to_representation` method of the serializer. This really seems to go against REST API design so I don't recommend it. You should create a separate serializer for TypeSerializer for the best result.

Add this method to the SchoolSerialzer to achieve your desired format:

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    rep = super().to_representation(obj)
    age = rep.pop('age')
    type_ = rep.pop('type')
    rep['type'] = {
        'age': age,
        'nationality': type_
    }
    return rep
```

Comment: Isn't this popping from the rep and putting it in that format? I'd like to take api in that format from the enduser.

Comment: This is for representation only. Doesn't affect the user input. Also, type and nationality fields seems to be duplicated.

Comment: I'm looking for best method. If this is against the design, what other method do you recommend

Comment: Your model is not in the correct format. You should be using a separate table for the SchoolType. You can use a TypeSerializer but even still you will have to override `the_representation` to populate it for reading.

Comment: I'm not looking to just override the to_rep.